# How to modify value of element in Firebase with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my Firebase data structure:

[image: See Example Here]

How to access/modify the value of the **status** child in my database?
I tried something like this but it does not work...

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['firebase']);

app.controller("todoctrl", ["$scope", "$firebaseArray",
  function($scope, $firebaseArray) {
    var list = $firebaseArray(new Firebase('https://todo-5a386.firebaseio.com/'));
    var status = list.child("status");
    // set status
    $scope.set() = function(){
        status.$set("$scope.status")
    };

  }
]);
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to accomplish.  Can you explain more?  Are you simply trying to access the status property or modify it too?

Comment: I want to modify the status property. Actually, i want to change status value from all, what is set now to to the value of ng-model="status".

Comment: Please elaborate on "does not work." You don't show where you're actually doing anything in the code, but at first glance $firebaseArray does not seem appropriate for the data sample. That's going to sync the entire contents of your database into an array-like structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for in order to be able to view and modify "status" in the DOM:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['firebase']);

app.controller("todoctrl", ["$scope", "$firebaseObject",
  function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
    var ref = new Firebase('https://todo-5a386.firebaseio.com/').child("status");

    //this will make status available to modify and usable in the DOM in ng-model or the like
    $scope.status = $firebaseObject(ref);

    $scope.status.$loaded().then(function(){
        //data is now loaded from firebase
        console.log("status: " + $scope.status);
    });

  }
]);
```

It can then be accesses in the DOM or modified such as:

```
<label>Firebase Status</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="status"/>
```

**EDIT**

To 3 way bind per the [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['firebase']);

app.controller("todoctrl", ["$scope", "$firebaseObject",
  function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
    var ref = new Firebase('https://todo-5a386.firebaseio.com/').child("status");

    //this will make status available to modify and usable in the DOM in ng-model or the like
    var obj = $firebaseObject(ref);

    obj.$loaded().then(function(){
        //data is now loaded from firebase
        console.log("status: " + obj);
    });


    $scope.status = obj;
    obj.$bindTo($scope, "status");
  }
]);
```

This should be 3-way bound so changes you make to status should be reflected in the database.